# How do I display most commented articles in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

I would love to work with the number of comments within one article in the asset publisher. For example, I would love:

- to display the most commented articles
- add tags to the articles with most comments

or something similar that enables me to select the most commented articles. What is the easiest way to start working with articles based on number of comments?

Any examples, code, API, and similar is highly welcome!

Answer (score 1):

For the second point the solution is easy: [Model Listener](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/model-listeners)

Just implement a model listener of comment (MBMessage should be the real name) and in the method onAfterCreate retrieve the article on which the comment has been posted and the total number of comment for it, then for example `if(totalArticleCommentNumber > 99)` add your tags.

Then in the configuration of the Asset Publisher you can select just the articles with your specific tag.

But, if you need some different logic (sort the articles by comment number for example) the case is more complex and you'll have to customize the Asset Publisher to add your new logic.

EDIT:
Some guide that may help you for customize the portal:

- [Overriding App JSP](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-a-modules-jsps)
- [Liferay 7 Portlet to Empower Your Custom Development](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/liferay-7-portlet-empower-your-custom-development-andrew-miller): In this article there is a lot of usefull things but I want point you to the paragraph 4.3, to summarize very shortly: If a class is a OSGI Component (so has the OSGI annotation `@Component`) you can extend that class and through the `service.ranking:Integer`  property of the annotation you can tell to Liferay that your class overrides the original service.

Comment: Well, I thought the sorting could be avoided by adding tags, such as "most commented", "second most commented" etc. but I see that the Model Listener is not ideal for that, since the articles wouldn't be in any particular order... Thank you for your help. Any pointers on customizing the Asset Publisher? I thought it was such a common thing that this has been solved long time ago (sorting articles based on num of comments :/ )